# Как реализовать данную блок схему через рекурсию?

Tags: c#, рекурсия

> Вы должны написать рекурсивный вызов функции  СhooseAction, тем самым создав прохождение по всему алгоритму, представленному в диаграмме. При первом вызове функции параметру previousAction нужно указать значение  “Начало дня”, При всяком последующем вызове этой функции вы должны указывать этому параметру значение, которое вернула функция в  предыдущем вызове.

Как я начал делать:

```
using System;

namespace MyProject
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static string[] variants =
            {
                    "Начало дня",
                    "Поднимаюсь с корвати с левой ноги",
                    "Поднимаюсь с корвати с правой ноги",
                    "Падаю с кровати",
                    "Пробежка по алее",
                    "Физ. зарядка на балконе",
                    "Варю крепкий кофе",
                    "Готовлю плотный завтрак",
                    "Достаю вчерашний салат",
                    "Спустило колесо",
                    "Добираюсь на работу пешком",
                    "Добираюсь на работу на маршрутке",
                    "Добираюсь на работу на своем авто",
                    "Прихожу вовремя",
                    "Опаздываю на работу",
                    "Конец",
            };
        static string[] resultActionList = new string [14];


        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ChooseAction(variants);

        }

        static void ChooseAction(string[] previousAction)
        {
            resultActionList[0] = previousAction[0];
            int firstChoose = ChooseVariant(1, 3);
            switch (firstChoose)
            {
                case 1:
                    resultActionList[1] = previousAction[1];
                    int firstActionChoose = ChooseVariant(1, 11);
                    if (firstActionChoose <= 7)
                        resultActionList[2] = previousAction[3];
                    else if (firstActionChoose >= 8)
                    {
                        int firstActionNewChoose = ChooseVariant(1, 7);
                        if (firstActionNewChoose <= 4)
                            resultActionList[2] = previousAction[4];
                        else if (firstActionNewChoose >= 5)
                            resultActionList[2] = previousAction[5];
                    }

                    break;
                case 2:
                    resultActionList[1] = previousAction[2];
                    int secondActionChoose = ChooseVariant(1, 7);
                    if (secondActionChoose <= 4)
                        resultActionList[2] = previousAction[4];
                    else if (secondActionChoose >= 5)
                        resultActionList[2] = previousAction[5];
                    break;
            }
            int thirdActionChoose = ChooseVariant(1, 13);
            if (thirdActionChoose <= 8)
                resultActionList[3] = previousAction[6];
            else if (thirdActionChoose >= 9)
            {
                int thirdActionNewChoose = ChooseVariant(1, 5);
                if (thirdActionNewChoose == 1)
                    resultActionList[3] = previousAction[7];
                else if (thirdActionNewChoose >= 2)
                {
                    resultActionList[3] = previousAction[8];
                }
            }
        }

        static int ChooseVariant(int maxForFirstVariant, int maxForSecondVariant)
        {
            Random random = new Random();
            int randomValue = random.Next(maxForFirstVariant, maxForSecondVariant);
            return randomValue;
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задача на использование шаблона проектирования "Конечный автомат". Суть шаблона заключается в неком переключателе, у которого есть 2 сущности "состояние" и "переход". Состояние - это точка входа в автомат. Переход - точка выхода.

Обычно конечные автоматы с помощью рекурсии не реализовывают, а просто крутят в бесконечном цикле, пока автомат не сообщит, что он закончил. Но раз просят рекурсию, дадим рекурсию.

Чтобы начать решать задачу, надо понять, где состояния и переходы находятся на вашей схеме. Блоки - это состояния, а стрелки - переходы. Давайте пронумеруем состояния.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Так как с C# всё нумеруется с нуля, я тоже пронумерую с нуля, можете считать это профдеформацией. :) В каком порядке нумеровать состояния - совершенно без разницы, не заостряйте на порядке внимание.

Далее, на схеме видно всего 2 типа блоков, один что-то выводит на экран, второй производит ветвление на основе генератора СЧ. Тот что что-то выводит назову `Print`, а тот что ветвится, назову `Branch`.

```
static void Print(string text)
{
    Console.WriteLine(text);
}

static Random rnd = new Random();

static int Branch(int max, int threshold, int nextLeft, int nextRight)
{
    return rnd.Next(max) + 1 < threshold ? nextLeft : nextRight;
}
```

У генератора `Random` есть нехорошие побочные свойства если его пересоздавать каждый раз когда нужно число, например он может легко нагенерить одинаковых чисел. Поэтому я создам его один раз и буду его же использовать для ветвления.

Как вы уже догадались из схемы, у вашего автомата будет 26 состояний. Метод перехода автомата из одного состояния в другое я неслучайно назову `MoveNext`, вы еще не раз встретите так названные методы в .NET, так что пригодится. Ну вот, собственно и всё, остальное дело техники.

```
static void MoveNext(int state)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 0: 
            Print("Начало дня"); 
            MoveNext(1); 
            break;
        case 1:
            MoveNext(Branch(2, 2, 2, 3));
            break;
        case 2:
            Print("Поднимаюсь с кровати с левой ноги");
            MoveNext(4);
            break;
        case 3:
            Print("Поднимаюсь с кровати с правой ноги");
            MoveNext(5);
            break;
        case 4:
            MoveNext(Branch(10, 8, 6, 5));
            break;
        case 5:
            MoveNext(Branch(6, 5, 7, 8));
            break;
        case 6:
            Print("Падаю с кровати");
            MoveNext(9);
            break;
        case 7:
            Print("Пробежка по алее");
            MoveNext(9);
            break;
        case 8:
            Print("Физ. зарядка на балконе");
            MoveNext(9);
            break;
        case 9:
            MoveNext(Branch(12, 9, 11, 10));
            break;
        case 10:
            MoveNext(Branch(4, 2, 12, 13));
            break;
        case 11:
            Print("Варю крепкий кофе");
            MoveNext(15);
            break;
        case 12:
            Print("Готовлю плотный завтрак");
            MoveNext(15);
            break;
        case 13:
            Print("Достаю вчерашний салат");
            MoveNext(15);
            break;
        case 14:
            Print("Спустило колесо");
            MoveNext(16);
            break;
        case 15:
            MoveNext(Branch(5, 3, 14, 19));
            break;
        case 16:
            MoveNext(Branch(8, 3, 17, 18));
            break;
        case 17:
            Print("Добираюсь на работу пешком");
            MoveNext(20);
            break;
        case 18:
            Print("Добираюсь на работу на маршрутке");
            MoveNext(21);
            break;
        case 19:
            Print("Добираюсь на работу на своем авто");
            MoveNext(22);
            break;
        case 20:
            MoveNext(Branch(8, 3, 23, 24));
            break;
        case 21:
            MoveNext(Branch(2, 2, 23, 24));
            break;
        case 22:
            MoveNext(Branch(8, 6, 23, 24));
            break;
        case 23:
            Print("Прихожу вовремя");
            MoveNext(25);
            break;
        case 24:
            Print("Опаздываю на работу");
            MoveNext(25);
            break;
        case 25:
            Print("Конец");
            break;
    }
}
```

Вы выносили все тексты в массив, но в рамках данной задачи это необязательно, хоть и не запрещено. Я не стал использовать массив, чтобы метод `MoveNext` читался проще.

Все готово. Запускаю:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MoveNext(0);
}
```

То есть стартую автомат с нулевого состояния.

Получаю вот такой вывод в консоль:

```
Начало дня
Поднимаюсь с кровати с левой ноги
Пробежка по алее
Достаю вчерашний салат
Добираюсь на работу на своем авто
Прихожу вовремя
Конец
```

Или такой:

```
Начало дня
Поднимаюсь с кровати с правой ноги
Пробежка по алее
Варю крепкий кофе
Спустило колесо
Добираюсь на работу на маршрутке
Опаздываю на работу
Конец
```

Как повезёт.

---

Вариант с циклом без рекурсии

```
static int MoveNext(int state)
{
    switch (state)
    {
        case 0: 
            Print("Начало дня"); 
            return 1; 
        case 1:
            return Branch(2, 2, 2, 3);
        case 2:
            Print("Поднимаюсь с кровати с левой ноги");
            return 4;
        case 3:
            Print("Поднимаюсь с кровати с правой ноги");
            return 5;
        case 4:
            return Branch(10, 8, 6, 5);
        case 5:
            return Branch(6, 5, 7, 8);
        case 6:
            Print("Падаю с кровати");
            return 9;
        case 7:
            Print("Пробежка по алее");
            return 9;
        case 8:
            Print("Физ. зарядка на балконе");
            return 9;
        case 9:
            return Branch(12, 9, 11, 10);
        case 10:
            return Branch(4, 2, 12, 13);
        case 11:
            Print("Варю крепкий кофе");
            return 15;
        case 12:
            Print("Готовлю плотный завтрак");
            return 15;
        case 13:
            Print("Достаю вчерашний салат");
            return 15;
        case 14:
            Print("Спустило колесо");
            return 16;
        case 15:
            return Branch(5, 3, 14, 19);
        case 16:
            return Branch(8, 3, 17, 18);
        case 17:
            Print("Добираюсь на работу пешком");
            return 20;
        case 18:
            Print("Добираюсь на работу на маршрутке");
            return 21;
        case 19:
            Print("Добираюсь на работу на своем авто");
            return 22;
        case 20:
            return Branch(8, 3, 23, 24);
        case 21:
            return Branch(2, 2, 23, 24);
        case 22:
            return Branch(8, 6, 23, 24);
        case 23:
            Print("Прихожу вовремя");
            return 25;
        case 24:
            Print("Опаздываю на работу");
            return 25;
        case 25:
            Print("Конец");
            break;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int state = 0;
    while (state != -1)
    {
        state = MoveNext(state);
    }
}
```

На мой взгляд он технически более правильный.

Comment: Боже это гениально. Так как я только начал обучение такие тонкости или же такие способы даже в голову не пришли бы. Огромное спасибо

Comment: @Avanlock Не за что, поищите больше информации про конечный автомат, еще его называют "машина состояний". Он очень популярен и встречается на каждом углу, в том числе в .NET вы еще не раз на него наткнетесь. Обязательно пригодится.

Comment: У меня возник еще один вопрос. Я решил задачу соблюдая все ТЗ и в итоге у меня получилось так что у меня есть массив в котором от выбора ветки записываются элементы с другого массива. Так вот у меня выдает пустой элемент так как в эту веку рандомайзер не вошел. И теперь при выводе конечного массива у меня пустой элемент присутствует что можно с ней сделать ? [https://prnt.sc/26wje3m]

Comment: @Avanlock но выше поставленный вопрос про блок-схему же решен, так? Если у вас появился новый вопрос, вы можете задать его отдельно. При чем тут массивы, я вообще не понял. Добавил еще одно решение в ответ. Если ответ был полезен, вы можете принять его. Если же нет, я могу его удалить и подождете другого ответа.