# Как правильно реализовать работу искусственного интеллекта в игре, чтобы не проседал FPS?

Tags: c#, winforms, разработка-игр, искусственный-интеллект

Создаю игру. В ней есть игрок и довольно много монстров (от 10 штук). Для монстров необходимо прописать элементарный ИИ, чтобы они могли бегать, прыгать и т.д. У меня получилось это сделать в отдельном классе:

```
public static class MonsterAI
{
    private static Timer actionTimer = new Timer() { Interval = 100 };
    public static void IdleMove(Monster monster)
    {
        actionTimer.Tick += (s, e) =>
        {
            if (monster.OnGround)
                monster.Jump();
        };
        actionTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Однако, когда я неоднократно вызываю этот метод, то фпс сильно просаживается и игра начинает сильно лагать. Вызываю я этот метод для каждого монстра. Насколько я понимаю, мне необходимо запускать этот метод в другом потоке, однако совершенно не понимаю как это реализовать. Была попытка, но она безуспешна:

```
public static class MonsterAI
{
    private static Timer actionTimer = new Timer() { Interval = 100 };
    public static void IdleMove(Monster monster)
    {
        actionTimer.Tick += async (s, e) =>
        {
            if (monster.OnGround)
                await Task.Run(() => { monster.Jump(); } );
        };
        actionTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: у тебя игра вроде на winform'ах? добавь метку если да

Comment: Первое, что я бы сделал - всех монстров в один таймер обновлений, а не создавать по таймеру на каждый чих

Comment: Отлично, большинство лагов пропало, однако, как можно запараллелить вызов этого метода?

Comment: Вы не можете параллелить UI. UI - это один поток. Из рабочих потоков вы не можете работать с контролами и обновлять интерфейс. В рабочих потоках может только происходить работа, не связанная с UI, а у вас ее скорее всего совсем немного, но вы не показали.

Comment: У вас лагает то, что вы не показали. Как рисуются элементы на форме - неизвестно, используете ли вы двойную буферизацию - тайна, как вы работаете с контролами - загадка. простейшая логика ИИ [реализуется](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1382349/373567) на шаблоне проектирования "конечный автомат", у вас что-то другое, что странно.