# нумерация при перезаписи в массив

Tags: c#

только начал изучать C# так что не ругайте строго
вопрос в том как правильно мне указывать нумерацию
то есть я перезаписываю через ресайз
дальше вопрос как правильно присвоить с индексом
и нужно ли увеличивать массив резалт на 1 после присвоения вариантс

```
 static string[] variants = {
                    "Начало дня", 
                    "Поднимаюсь с кровати с левой ноги",
                    "Поднимаюсь с кровати с правой ноги",
                    "Падаю с кровати",
                    "Пробежка по аллее",
                    "Физ. зарядка на балконе",
                    "Варю крепкий кофе",
                   "Готовлю плотный завтрак",
                    "Достаю вчерашний салат",
                    "Спустило колесо",
                     "Добираюсь на работу пешком",
                     "Добираюсь на работу на маршрутке",
                     "Добираюсь на работу на своем авто",
                    "Прихожу вовремя",
                     "Опаздываю на работу",
                     "Конец"
                };
                static string[] resultActionList;
  

 

switch (previousAction)
            {
                case "Начало дня":
                   var choseOne = ChooseVariant(1, 2);
                    switch (choseOne)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            ChooseAction(variants[1]);
                            resultActionList[0]=variants[0];
                            Array.Resize(ref resultActionList, resultActionList.Length +1);
                            break;

                        case 2:
                            ChooseAction(variants[2]);
                            resultActionList[0]=variants[0];
                            Array.Resize(ref resultActionList, resultActionList.Length +1);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case "Поднимаюсь с кровати с левой ноги":
                    var choseMain = ChooseVariant(7, 10);
                    switch (choseMain)
                    {
                        case 1:
                            ChooseAction(variants[3]);
                            Array.Resize(ref resultActionList, resultActionList.Length +1);
                            resultActionList[1] = variants[3];
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            var choseMainOne = ChooseVariant(4, 6);
                            switch (choseMainOne)
                            {
                                case 1:
                                    ChooseAction(variants[4]);
                                    Array.Resize(ref resultActionList, resultActionList.Length +1);
                                    resultActionList[1] = variants[2];
                                    break;
                                case 2:
                                    ChooseAction(variants[5]);
                               Array.Resize(ref resultActionList, resultActionList.Length+1);
                                    resultActionList[1] = variants[3];
                                    break;
                            }
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Не мучайтесь с этими ресайзами, есть же `List<T>`, специально предназначенный для работы с коллекцией переменной длины, ему можно `Add` и `Remove` делать, и по индексам он тоже работает. Кстати, что-то ваш вопрос мне напоминает https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1382349/373567, кажется там решено уже то, что вам нужно безо всяких массивов.

Comment: а зачем вы используете свитчкейсы с одинаковым кодом? там можно элементарно заменить `variants[1]` на `variants[choseOne]`, остальной код одинаковый